# Centos 5.11 No module named yum

Tags: centos, yum, python

I'm running Centos 5.11 and I installed python 2.7 (replacing 2.4) I soon found out that yum won't work with 2.7, as expected if I put `python -V` it shows Python 2.7.

My classmate did a snapshot of the Virtual machine where CentOS is running before I installed 2.7. He restored the snapshot, now when I type `python -V` it shows 2.4 but yum still does not work showing:

> It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
>   current version of Python, which is:
>   2.7.9 (default, Feb 23 2016, 18:55:48)

So even though `python -V` shows 2.4 yum still shows 2.7. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to have to revert to an earlier snapshot, because Python 2.7 is interfering with Yum, so it's likely that the snapshot wasn't early enough.  Undoing an accidentally overwritten Python is a pretty advanced procedure.

It can be done, but if you're somewhat new to Linux, it's much faster, easier, and less error prone to backup your system and reinstall.  Repairing this is not too dissimilar from correcting an overwritten libc.

Once you get that sorted out, you'll want to install Python 2.7 using "make altinstall" instead of "make install".  Be sure to install the new Python into a different place than your system's native Python 2.4.  /usr/local is a reasonable location, although some people prefer /opt.

For example:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make && make altinstall
```